# How to always position a control to a fixed location on screen in silverlight on wp7?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

How can I always position a silverlight control on screen at the same location regardless of the text-box the client changes focus to? Basically I have a header banner that I want visible at all times. When the client changes focus to a text-box, I want all the content to scroll to bring the text-box into center view(this is the default behavior) except for the banner which should always displayed at (0,0) screen coordinates. What I have so far for the layout is:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Name="myBanner"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Height="80"
               Width="480" />

    <TextBox Grid.Row="2"
             Name="textBox1"
             Text="TextBox"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Height="72"
             Width="480"
             />                  <--- Even when client focuses on this I want myBanner to be visible at (0,0) screen coordinate
</Grid>
```

An example of this can been seen in the texting app on the phone. Regardless of if the client has focused to text message writing text-box the title at the top "John Doe, Text" appears at the same position all the time.

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

        <RowDefinition />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <!-- Your banner goes here-->
     <TextBlock Text="some text" />
     <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
         <!-- Your content goes here-->
     </ScrollViewer>

  </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not quite fix the problem. Where you have <!-- Your content goes here--> If I insert a <TextBox /> and focus to it, the banner is no long visible as the whole screen has scrolled up when the keyboard entered.